# JavaScript regular expression to check time format

Tags: javascript, regex, time, onchange

I would like to have a regular expression which clears an HTML field when the input is not correct. I created this one, but instead of clearing the field when it's incorrect, it clears it only when the input *is* correct.

```
onchange="this.value=this.value.replace(/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/,'')"
```

I've tried to 'reverse' the code, but it didn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onchange="if (!this.value.match(/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/)) this.value = '';"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/.test(this.value)) this.value="";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onchange="this.value=
/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/.test(this.value) ? this.value : ''"
```

Comment: The syntax of `test()` is incorrect (the object and parameter need to be swapped), and there's an unnecessary `''` parameter leftover from the question code.

Comment: It runs in fiddle, but in a standalone web page, the same code used on fiddle crashes. I tested it in FF, Chrome, and IE9. String objects do not have a test() method, regular expression objects do. In Firebug, I get the error: `value.test is not a function`.